# Receive data from NSURLConnection periodically

Tags: iphone, refresh, nsurlconnection, intervals

I am using NSURLConnection to receive some data (in JSON) and do some work (e.g. write data to a label) in connectionDidFinishLoading method. What I want is, this should happen e.g. every two seconds. That is, ReceiveData > WriteDataToLabel > Wait 2 seconds > ReceiveData ...
In other words, I want to update my data every two seconds. Of course, this should be done in background not to block app.

What should be done? Do I need runloop, nstimer or NSOperation and how should I use them?

Comment: Sounds like you want to do polling. Do take into account that it's not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I learned that you can do this using NSTimer. It is pretty easy.

Check out this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html

(You may also consider @Aaron's words)

Answer (score 0):

Question is *"What should be done ?"*

I believe the answer is *"Not This"*

Not a recommended approach to be pinging the server every two seconds from every device that has your application running

Comment: Let me clear the situation: I have real-time location information on the database and I should receive the location and immediately display it on the map. So I thought, I should call the web service (which is a JSON file) every two seconds. Are there any other way to do this ?